# Functions for boolean operators, that return 1 or 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Are there any purely mathematical expressions that are equivalent to boolean operators and return $1$ or $0$?

For example: $a > b$

Is there any $f(a, b)$ for which if $a>b$, $f(a,b)=1$ and if $a < b$, $f(a,b)=0$? 
Can you express such a function with a simple expression and with no branches/multiple definitions ?

Comment: See [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the absolute value, for example, a possible expression is $f(a,b)=\frac12\Big(1+\frac{a-b}{|a-b|}\Big)$. If you don't like the absolute value this can be rewritten as $f(a,b)=\frac12\left(1+\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{(a-b)^2}}\right)$.

Comment: Perfect, this was also the expression I got, unfortunately it's undefined for (0,0) or for when a=b, and I can't seem to find a solution for this exception (other beside shifting the domain of the function with a big delta)

Comment: OP only specified the function for a>b  and a<b , so it shouldn't matter what happens for a=b.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [Iverson Bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket):
$$f(x,y) = [x>y]$$

Answer (score 2):

$H(a-b)$, where $H$ stands for the Heaviside step function (the primitive of the Dirac $\delta$).

Also, $H(x)=\frac{sgn(x)+1}{2}=\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{e^{ax}+1}$.

Comment: The heaviside and dirac functions are expressed with 2 definitions/branches

Comment: My computer has it as a built-in operation.